# amazon-redshift : select id, first(a),sum(b) group by id

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, greatest-n-per-group

In mysql/SparkSQL we have `first` function. which doesn't exist in Redshift.

I have to change code

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  first(product_code) as product_code,
  first(product_name) as product_name,
  first(time_date) as time_date, 
  max(price_max) as price_max,
  min(price_min) as price_min,
  sum(count_of_sales) as count_of_sales,
  SUM(CASE WHEN time_date = 1538323200000 THEN cost_of_stock_start ELSE 0 END) as cost_of_stock_start,
from storeproductincomelogs 
WHERE time_date>= 1538323200000 
  AND time_date<= 1541001600000 
group by product_id;
```

to

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  product_code,
  product_name,
  min(time_date) as time_date,  # have to change first to min, this column can't group by
  max(price_max) as price_max,
  min(price_min) as price_min,
  sum(count_of_sales) as count_of_sales,
  SUM(CASE WHEN time_date = 1538323200000 THEN cost_of_stock_start ELSE 0 END) as cost_of_stock_start,
from storeproductincomelogs 
WHERE time_date>= 1538323200000 
  AND time_date<= 1541001600000 
group by product_id,product_code,product_name;
```

Without `first`, I have to add `product_code,product_name` in group by clasuse.
Or would get error:

> Invalid operation: column "storeproductincomelogs.product_code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;

Note: here `product_id,product_code` are unique in each row, and duplicated `product_name` is also hardly found (but may be appear in future so I think I can't use group by).

---

I searched mysql `first` equivalent in postgresql and got [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) .

First, I tried [`Distinct on` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/1637673) which is not supported in Redshift.

Then, I tried:

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT product_id,
           product_code,
           product_name,
            min(time_date) as time_date,
            max(price_max) as price_max,
            sum(count_of_sales) as count_of_sales,
            SUM(CASE WHEN time_date = 1538323200000 THEN cost_of_stock_start ELSE 0 END) as cost_of_stock_start,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id ) AS rk
      FROM  storeproductincomelogs)
SELECT *
  FROM summary
 WHERE rk = 1;
```

got error

> [42803][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: column "storeproductincomelogs.product_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;

I don't know how to write correct one, so can't test the performance.

How can I do this in Redshift?

Comment: what is your expected output ? and it would be good if you provide your sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you don't want to group by `product_code` and `product_name` because there is a tiny possibility that they are not always the same for a given product id.

So, then I would suggest to just take `min` (or `max`) of those two fields also:

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  min(product_code) as product_code,
  min(product_name) as product_name,
  min(time_date) as time_date,
  max(price_max) as price_max,
  ... ...
group by product_id;
```

Comment: `first in order by product id` is fine.  `product_id` would not be duplicated, `product_code` and `product_code` are for better view, they may have duplicates but not seriously . Because I need dump the result to xlsx.

Comment: Understand, I need add `OVER(PARTITION BY product_id )` for each column which need aggregation .  But it become extemely slow,  much more slow than group by .

Comment: I suppose you have an index on `storeproductincomlogs.product_id`?

Comment: I also noted in your question that you have a field `time_date`: that seems a good candidate for the `order by` in the window.

Comment: Index is not supported and no need in redshift(column-oriented DBMS). I don't need order by too . Atcually there is more than 10 column need `sum` 
 ,`product_code, product_name, time_date` are only for better view.

Comment: In fact, in your `group by product_id,product_code,product_name;` attempt you should not get that error that you mentioned in the question. Are you sure you don't reference `product_code` elsewhere in the query?

Comment: `group by product_id,product_code,product_name` does not cause that error . But I only want `group by product_id`, that is the key problem . As I said in question, `product_name` is also hardly found (but may be appear in future so I think I can't use group by)

Comment: What do you mean with "hardly found"?

Comment: Now, there is no duplicated `product_name`, but may have in future .

Comment: Oh, you mean that for the same product id, you would have two different names?

Comment: Yes! That is I want to avoid .

Comment: But in that case, why not do `select ... min(product_name) as product_name, ...`?

Comment: product_name is sting , can use ` min ` ??

Comment: Wow, I have never heard this , it works , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - you need to add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id order by price_max desc)` which will give you product wise max price

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT product_id,
           product_code,
           product_name,
           price_max,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id order by price_max desc) AS rk
      FROM  storeproductincomelogs)
SELECT *
  FROM summary
 WHERE rk = 1;
```

Comment: No, you can't use order by to trick `max`. How do you cope with `sum` and `min` in same time ?